# THINGSBOARD REST API CALL Node

Tags: rest, curl, thingsboard

Please be kind and tell me how to execute the following CURL command with REST API Call node from Thingsboard 2.5.2:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{"username":"tenant@thingsboard.org", "password":"mypassword"}' 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/auth/login'
```

How can I send the `-d '{"username":"tenant@thingsboard.org", "password":"mypassword"}'` to the REST API CALL node?

Comment: What do you mean? Install curl, open a terminal, paste the command and press return?

Answer (score 0):

As described on the [documentation page](https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/rest-api/), the first step is indeed to `POST` on `/api/auth/login` providing a username and password in order to retrieve a JWT token. This is the first step you described in your `curl` call.

Then, for further calls to other API endpoints, you must send a `X-Authorization` HTTP header with the `Bearer: $TOKEN` as a value.

Note that if you want to interact with the Thingsboard administration API with Java or Python, clients are available to abstract this.